# TSQL - extract data to table/view to speed up query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, triggers, sql-server-2012

I use this statement to create a list for excel

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year, Version 
    FROM myView 
    WHERE id <> 'old' 
    ORDER BY Year DESC, Version DESC
```

The problem is that the execution time is over 30s because of the almost 2 million rows.

The result has only around 1000 rows.

What are my options to extract only those two columns in order to speed up the execution time? I also need to make sure that inserts to the underlying table are recognized.

Do I need a new table to copy the values from the view? And a trigger to manage the updates?

Thank you

Comment: Could you post your table definition? including indexes?

Comment: Are those three columns `Year`, `Version`, `id` all from the same table?

Comment: Since this is a view I have to ask, does that view reference another view? The most likely issue is the nonSARGable predicate <> in your where clause. That will cause a table/index scan no matter what you do.

Comment: You could create an index SPECIFIC to this query... a filtered index on "Year DESC, Version DESC" where the filter is id <> 'old' ... this query would then use this index and it would be very fast.  However, that index wouldn't be used by any other query, and any updates, inserts, and deletes will have to update this index.

Comment: - there are no indexes defined for that table (and it wouldn't work for this table) 
- all columns are from the same table
- that's why I believe it might be better to create an extra table for those two columns

Comment: I honestly don't understand your last comment.  The reason it's slow is because there are no indexes... but then you say you need to create a new table?  Why?  Just create an index on the existing table as I described... Even if you're selecting from a view, those columns should exist in the underlying table, and that table can be indexed... the select from the view will use the table index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, presumably there's a table with Year and id underlying your view.  Given this (trivial) example:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable ([id] varchar(10), [Year] int, [Version] int);
```

Just create an index on that table that matches the way you're querying your data.  Given your query of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year, Version 
  FROM myView 
 WHERE id <> 'old' 
 ORDER BY Year DESC, Version DESC
```

This query matches the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses and should give you all the performance you need:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myTable]') AND name = N'IX_YearVersion_Filtered')
    DROP INDEX [IX_YearVersion_Filtered] ON [dbo].[myTable] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_YearVersion_Filtered] ON [dbo].[myTable] 
(
    [Year] DESC,
    [Version] DESC
)
WHERE ([id]<>'old')
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte_x
as
(SELECT Year, Version 
    FROM myView 
    WHERE id not in ('old')
    group by Year, Version)
SELECT DISTINCT Year, Version 
    FROM cte_x
        ORDER BY Year DESC, Version DESC
```

Comment: thanks for the example - however the query is only a few seconds faster